# Open JPA cascade delete issue

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have entity as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BENEFICIARY")
public class Beneficiary {

//other fields from entity

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "BENEFICIARY_BANK_ID", nullable = false)
private Bank beneficiaryBank;
}
```

deleting beneficiary by calling entitymanager.remove()

```
@Override
public void remove(E entity) {
entityManager.remove(entity);
}
```

but sometime I got error as following,

```
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_BENEFIC_BENEF_5629CD9C". The conflict occurred in database "XXXX_DB", table "dbo.BENEFICIARY", column 'BENEFICIARY_BANK_ID'. {prepstmnt 596583311 DELETE FROM dbo.BANK WHERE ID = ? [params=?]} [code=547, state=23000]
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:273)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:261)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$1200(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:70)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeBatch(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1187)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:260)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeBatch(JDBCStoreManager.java:1720)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.executeBatch(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:356)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushBatch(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:187)
... 56 more
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
```

Looks like exception is due to open jpa trying yo delete beneficiary table data before bank table data. I am clueless why this is happening as I am giving a CascadeType.ALL it JPA should delete data from beneficiary first and then from the bank table
do anybody have idea about this issue's solution?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please Specify the version of JPA

Comment: I read this as that the data being cascade deleted is ALSO referenced by another entity, which would lead to a integrity constraint violation if it was allowed to happen. Perhaps you need to decouple the entity you want to cascade-delete from somewhere else too before this can work. JPA is not a magic wand, its still you in control. It can only help you so far.

Comment: I have checked constraint for BANK table is not coupled with any other table.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems like openJPA doesn't behave as defined in the spec.